# Change the background color of the first row in Helper WebGrid MVC without JQuery

Tags: model-view-controller, webgrid

I would like to change the background color of the first row in a WebHelper WebGrid for MVC without the use of JQuery.

Any Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@model IEnumerable<MyViewModel>

@{
    var indexedModel = Model.Select((item, index) => new { Element = item, Index = index });
    var grid = new WebGrid(indexedModel);
}

@grid.GetHtml(
    columns: grid.Columns(
        grid.Column(
            columnName: "item.MyProperty", 
            header: "Myproperty",
            format: 
                @<text>
                    <div@Html.Raw(item.Index == 0 ? " class=\"firstRow\"" : "")>
                        @item.Element.MyProperty
                    </div>
                </text>
        )
    )
)
```

and in your CSS:

```
.firstRow {
    background-color: Red;
}
```

Comment: Wow, Darin thanks so much, I knew there had to be a way without JQuery!

Comment: sorry @Darin Dimitrov but that injects a <DIV> after the <TD>. I need the entire row in this case.

Comment: @HarHaHu, sorry, that's not possible. The WebGrid doesn't allow you to set any styles on the `<tr>`. Your only hope in this case is javascript.

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion could be in each columns's format parameter, use an if-else situation based on a distinct variable that will wrap the data in a span with a css.  A bit cumbersome but should work.

For this reason some JQuery would potentially be easier.